# Trait ManageConnection not implemented for DieselConnectionManager<PgConnection> in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am having a problem with the `DieselConnectionManager<PgConnection>` type from the `bb8-diesel` crate in my Rust project. Specifically, the error message says:

> the trait `ManageConnection` is not implemented for `DieselConnectionManager<PgConnection>`

This issue arose when trying to use Diesel version 2.0.3 and bb8-diesel version 0.2.1.

Here is the relevant part of my Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "uchat_query"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
bb8 = "0.8.0"
bb8-diesel = { version = "0.2.1" }
chrono = { version = "0.4.23", features = ["serde"] }
diesel-derive-newtype = "2.0.0-rc.0"
diesel_migrations = { version = "2.0.0", features = ["postgres"] }
password-hash = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["std"] }
r2d2 = "0.8.10"
serde = { version = "1.0.152", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.93"
thiserror = "1.0.38"
tokio = { version = "1.25.0", features = ["full"] }
tracing = { version = "0.1.37", features = ["attributes"] }
url = { version = "2.2.2" }
uuid = { version = "1.3.0", features = ["v4", "serde"] }

[dependencies.diesel]
features = [
  "postgres",
  "uuid",
  "chrono",
  "serde_json",
  "i-implement-a-third-party-backend-and-opt-into-breaking-changes",
  "postgres_backend",
]
version = "2.0.3"
default-features = false

[dev-dependencies]
dotenvy = "0.15.7"
uchat_crypto = { path = "../crypto" }
```

And here is the relevant part of my Rust code where the error occurs:

> type AsyncConnectionManager = bb8_diesel::DieselConnectionManager;

I've tried updating the bb8-diesel crate to the latest version, and also tried downgrading Diesel to version 1.4.5, but neither of these options solved my problem.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Is there something I'm missing about how these two crates are supposed to interact, or is there a problem with their compatibility?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

code :

*

````
use diesel::{ConnectionError, PgConnection};
use diesel_migrations::{embed_migrations, EmbeddedMigrations, MigrationHarness};
use std::{error::Error, time::Duration};
use bb8::ManageConnection;
use crate::error::QueryError;
pub const MIGRATIONS: EmbeddedMigrations = embed_migrations!("../migrations");
type AsyncConnectionManager = bb8_diesel::DieselConnectionManager<PgConnection>;
pub type AsyncConnection<'a> = bb8::PooledConnection<'a, AsyncConnectionManager>;
pub type OwnedAsyncConnection = bb8::PooledConnection<'static, AsyncConnectionManager>;
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct AsyncConnectionPool(bb8::Pool<AsyncConnectionManager>);
impl AsyncConnectionPool {
    pub async fn new<S: AsRef<str>>(url: S) -> Result<Self, QueryError> {
        let pool = new_async_pool(url).await?;
        {
            // check connection
            let _ = pool
                .0
                .get()
                .await
                .map_err(|e| QueryError::Connection(e.to_string()))?;
        }
        Ok(pool)
    }
    pub async fn get(&self) -> Result<AsyncConnection, QueryError> {
        self.0
            .get()
            .await
            .map_err(|e| QueryError::Connection(e.to_string()))
    }
    pub async fn get_owned(&self) -> Result<OwnedAsyncConnection, QueryError> {
        self.0
            .get_owned()
            .await
            .map_err(|e| QueryError::Connection(e.to_string()))
    }
    pub fn state(&self) -> bb8::State {
        self.0.state()
    }
}
/// Run database migrations
pub fn run_migrations(
    connection: &mut impl MigrationHarness<diesel::pg::Pg>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'static>> {
    connection.run_pending_migrations(MIGRATIONS)?;
    Ok(())
}
/// Connect to the database
pub fn connect<S: AsRef<str>>(url: S) -> Result<PgConnection, ConnectionError> {
    use diesel::Connection;
    let url = url.as_ref();
    PgConnection::establish(url)
}
/// Usage:
/// ```
/// let async_pool = new_async_pool("postgres://login@localhost/sample").await;
/// let conn = &mut async_pool.get().await?;
/// ```
pub async fn new_async_pool<S: AsRef<str>>(url: S) -> Result<AsyncConnectionPool, QueryError> {
    let url = url.as_ref();
    let manager = bb8_diesel::DieselConnectionManager::<PgConnection>::new(url);
    bb8::Pool::builder()
        .test_on_check_out(true)
        .connection_timeout(Duration::from_secs(10))
        .build(manager)
        .await
        .map(AsyncConnectionPool)
        .map_err(|e| QueryError::Pool(e.to_string()))
}
````

- 

Comment: Please post a **minimal reproducible** example, and the full error from `cargo check` (not your IDE).

Answer (score 0):

The provided minimal example is not complete, especially your `Cargo.toml` file and also your code. It seems like you are mixing types from `bb8-diesel`, `diesel` and `diesel-async` based on the types names. `bb8-diesel` seems to only support diesel 1.4.x, while your example uses diesel > 2.0.
It's impossible to write more based on the provided information because you did not really provide the necessary information.